# A Simple GUI Interface for Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border-layout

doing some self study for a simple GUI interface for Java. Tried to code a simple interface. Here is the below code:

```
public void MainPanel() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Title");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane mpt = new JTabbedPane();

    mpt.addTab("Intro", new IntroPanel());
    mpt.addTab("Catalogue", new CataloguePanel());
    mpt.addTab("Order", new OrderPanel());
    mpt.addTab("Track", new TrackPanel());

    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setBackground(Color.white);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Intro");

    main.add(label1);
    frame.add(main);
    frame.add(mpt);       
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem I am currently facing is: If I put `frame.add(main)` infront of `frame.add(mpt)`, only the tabs will appear but the the label intro. If I put `frame.add(mpt)` infront of `frame.add(main)`. Intro will appear but not the tabs.

Why is this happening? Why are they overlapping each other? I did it the same way as some tutorial but to no avail..

Comment: Please assign some height to your tabbedPane and Jpanel, these are getting 100% height bydefault and overlapping each other so for test you can assign them a custom height to both or you can use JGrid to arrange your components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving it some other layout.

eg. `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Info:

According to Java Naming Conventions your method's name should be like `public void mainPanel()`

Comment: i did frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); and the layout is pretty ugly. I wanna have the tabs on top then the wordings and information below. how can i achieve that

Comment: and Why cant i navigate through my tabs?

Comment: @John read Oracle tutorial How to use BorderLayout, because JFrame has implemented BorderLayout in API

Comment: How about navigation through the tabs?